# Adding hours and days to the python datetime

Tags: python, django

I have a string in the following format

```
2021-05-06 17:30
```

How do I convert this to a python `datetime` and add a certain number of hours (e.g 4 hours)?

I also need to add a certain number of days to the string `2021-05-06`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

origin_date = datetime.strptime("2021-05-06 17:30","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
three_hour_later = origin_date + timedelta(hours=3)

print(datetime.strftime(three_hour_later,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

Please check this link.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 7):

You can first parse the string to a `datetime` object, and then use a `timedelta` to add days, hours, etc. to the item.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime.strptime('2021-05-06 17:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
print(dt + timedelta(hours=4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the timedelta method available on datetime object to add days, hours, minutes or seconds to the date.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

additional_hours = 4
additional_days = 2

old_date = datetime.strptime('2021-05-06 17:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
new_date = old_date + timedelta(hours=additional_hours, days=additional_days)

print(new_date)
```